# matplotlib contour label location manual failed

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am finding the way that manually set the position of contour labels in `matplotlib`, following the demo code of `contour_demo.py`, and the help doc of `contour`, I just use the code in `python2.7`:

```
plt.clabel(CS, inline=0, inline_spacing = 5,manual = True)
```

But it raises an error of `NotImplementedError`. when I set `manual = False`, there are no errors, but the labels are set automatic.

My question is how to set the position of label **manually**? Or how can I get the position on the figure by mouse click ,from this I can set the label position by:

```
manual_locations = [(-1, -1.4), (-0.62, -0.7), (-2, 0.5), (1.7, 1.2), (2.0, 1.4), (2.4, 1.7)]

plt.clabel(CS, inline=1, fontsize=10, manual=manual_locations)
```

Comment: What is your matplotlib version?

Comment: thanks for your reply. my matplotlib version are 1.5.3 in windows 64 bit.

Comment: try updating it - I can run `plt.clabel` with `manual = True` with no problems on a newer version of `matplotlib` (2.x).

Comment: thank you! I found it's because of my spyder can't show figure outside. I can run plt.clabel  using sublime text with no problems.

Comment: keep in mind that you can always [write an answer to your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).